# How to pass an ArrayList from Activity to a Fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, arraylist

What I'm trying to do is send an `ArrayList<String>` from an **Activity** to a **ListFragment**.

So I can use the Fragments in a `TableLayout`.

It's not necessary to use a `ListFragment`, I can use any type of `Fragment`, but I'm trying to get the idea.

Here's my **MainActivity**:

```
FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction;

ArrayList<String> namesArray = new ArrayList<>();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    namesArray.add("Android");
    namesArray.add("Iphone");
    namesArray.add("Windows Phone");

    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putStringArrayList("valuesArray", namesArray);
    namesFragment myFragment = new namesFragment();
    myFragment.setArguments(bundle);

    fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.main_container, new namesFragment());
    fragmentTransaction.commit();

}
```

My **ListFragment**:

```
@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    ArrayList<String> values = getArguments().getStringArrayList("valuesArray");

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, values);

    setListAdapter(adapter);
}
```

This code above gives me:

> Unfortunately app has stopped.

So how can I achieve something like that?

Comment: Post the logcat error please

Comment: As _Juan_ mentioned, you should always post your logcat error message when you get a crash like this, so we can more easily find out what is causing the crash. Also, you mention "_And how to display the ArrayList in the Fragment as a ListView_" - this should be posted as a separate question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are instantiating your `Fragment` twice.

Just change your code to:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    namesArray.add("Android");
    namesArray.add("Iphone");
    namesArray.add("Windows Phone");
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putStringArrayList("valuesArray", namesArray);
    namesFragment myFragment = new namesFragment();
    myFragment.setArguments(bundle);
    fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.main_container, myFragment);
    fragmentTransaction.commit();
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Not the answer but you can  avoid creating a Fragment Transaction object  by replacing last three lines with this

```
getSupportFragmentManager()
.beginTransaction()
.add(R.id.main_container, new namesFragment())
.commit();
```